# I have put the following in the web.xml of my application to attempt to disallow PUT, DELETE, etc

Tags: https, http, http-headers

I have put the following in the web.xml of my application to attempt to disallow PUT, DELETE, etc. but this below message shows

HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Allow: HEAD, DELETE, POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT
Content-Length: 0
Date: Thu, 09 Jan 2020 11:08:20 GMT

Comment: I think you'd need to at least tell what server you're using and maybe a snippet of the web.xml file. Also, not sure if the question isn't best suited for stackoverflow or the webmasters site.

Comment: I am using tomcat version 8+